# How to open front camera in Android? Why the code is wrong?

Tags: android

```
private Camera camera;
camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
```

Why does it tell me it can not find the `CameraInfo` class?

Comment: do have the right imports?

Answer (score 0):

When using Android classes, check the docs for the "Added in API level X" notation.  You'll see on CameraInfo (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html) it says "Added in API level 9", so you must ensure you're building with a minimum of this library, and also that devices that your app may run on also have this build level (or greater).

You need to set your minSdkVersion="9" (or greater), and your Project Build Target must be set to a minimum of API level 9, as CameraInfo was added at api 9.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Further, ensure you have the correct imports

```
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
```